# How many ways are there to draw $k$ red balls in $d$ draws(with replacement) from a bag of $n$ balls where $m$ of them are red and the rest are blue?

Tags: combinatorics

I started with a simple example, but I'd like to generalize my solution.

If I have to draw $4$ balls at random from a bag with replacement ($3$ red $2$ blue balls).

How many combinations result in

1. $0$ red balls ( $1$ way )
2. $1$ red ball ( $4$ way )
3. $2$ red balls ( $6$ way )
4. so on.. with $3$ red balls & $4$ red balls

As the number of balls drawn out is only $4$ its easy for me to just count the combinations

I want to understand how this can be calculated using the basic $^nC_r$ and $^nP_r$ formulas and explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To simplify the question: does it matter how many red balls are in the bag? Does it matter how many blue balls are in the bag? Those would only matter if it was probabilistic or if the balls were unique in some way. I suppose you care about order drawn: so to get 1 red ball you can draw: RBBB, BRBB,BBRB, or BBBR, correct?

Comment: @mark You seem to be right, it looks like it doesn't matter. But I am not 100% sure of the implication so I decided to give the additional information.

Comment: @Mark I think I figured it out, If i am not wrong the number of outcomes is nCr where (n = total population (4) , r = total red balls) eg. 2 red balls = 4C2 = 6.

Comment: @Mark now my next question is to find the formula to calculate that the total outcomes is 16. Generalizing further we can say that every time I pick a ball I can have either red or blue which is = 2 outcomes. So .. if I do it 4 times it will be 2x2x2x2 = 16. But can also be generalized right >?

Comment: Yes, if all we care about is whether a red ball or blue ball is selected, the number of selections with exactly $k$ red balls in $n$ trials  is $\binom{n}{k}$ since we must select which $k$ of the $n$ positions in the sequence will be filled with red balls.  Moreover, the total number of possibilities is $\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$.  The latter result can be obtained from the Binomial Theorem by substituting $1$ for both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you.